# How can I delete duplicated values in an array while counting the repetitions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to count the amount of times that a value appears in an array, and delete the repeated values keeping just the first.
So I can store in another array the amount of times that it appears, and it will have the same index as the value in the other array.

The loops I have tried don't count the amount of times correctly or delete other values that shouldn't be the ones deleted.

```
                            var itemCount = [];
var itemsName = ["aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd"]

                     for (let index = 0; index < itemsName.length; index++) {
        
                        for (var i = index + 1; i < itemsName.length; ++i) {
                          itemCount[index] = 1
      if (itemsName[i] === itemsName[index]){
                                itemCount[index]++;
                                itemsName.splice(i, 1)
                            }
                                
                        }
        
        
                                if (itemCount[index] > 1) {
                                    console.log(itemsName[index] + itemCount[index])
                                } else {
                                    console.log(itemsName[index])
                                }
                            
        
        
                        }
```

So the output should be like,
aaa3 bbb ccc ddd2

Comment: Share what you've already tried.

Comment: please add `itemsName` and the wanted results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code

```js
const itemsName = ["aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd"];
const itemCount = {}; // It's better to set this as an object.

for (let index = 0; index < itemsName.length; index++) {
    // index is a key and not the value of the array.
    // itemsName[index] will give you the value of an item in the array

    // Here I check if the key exists, incrementing it or setting it to 1.
    if (itemCount[itemsName[index]]) itemCount[itemsName[index]]++;
    else itemCount[itemsName[index]] = 1;
}

for (let key in itemCount) {
    console.log(key + itemCount[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove an entry from an array you change the index of subsequent entries. Thus you cannot keep the old index in the new array you create for duplicates.

What you can do is create two separate arrays, one without duplicates, the other containing objects with the duplicates and their index.

```
var itemsName = [...]; 
var newArray = []; 
var duplicatesArray = [];
var duplicateCount = 0;

// map creates a new array with the return statement
newArray = itemsName.map((entry,index) => {
   // check if the new array includes the current entry iteration
   if ( newArray.inculdes(entry) ) {
      duplicateCount++; // just the duplicate counter
      let duplicate = { oldIndex: index, value: entry }; // duplicate entry containing the oldIndex well .. index. This is so that you can get the index of the entry in the old array.
      duplicatesArray.push(duplicate); // add entry to duplicateArray
      return; // finish iteration without adding the entry to the new array
   }    
   return e; // add iteration entry to the new array
});
```

This should be it. =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array to keep track of the item count, use an object instead. You can use the item name as object key to quickly find the current count and increment it.

```js
const itemsName = ["aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd", "1", 1];
const itemCount = {};

for (const name of itemsName) {
  itemCount[name] ||= 0;
  itemCount[name]  += 1;
}

console.log("unique values", Object.keys(itemCount));
console.log("itemCount", itemCount);
```

[`||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) is a fairly new operator, if you are not using a transpiler (like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) to support older browsers you might want to use the following instead:

```
if (!itemCount[name]) itemCount[name] = 0;
```

Note that when using objects the all keys are converted to strings. So `"1"` and `1` are considered the same. If you want to differentiate between strings, numbers, complex objects (by identity, not value), etc. use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

```js
const itemsName = ["aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd", "1", 1];
const itemCount = new Map();

for (const name of itemsName) {
  if (!itemCount.has(name)) itemCount.set(name, 0);
  itemCount.set(name, itemCount.get(name) + 1);
}

console.log("unique values", Array.from(itemCount.keys()));
for (const [name, count] of itemCount) {
  console.log(typeof name, name, count);
}
```